# ProtoBuf-net invalid behaviour when serializing object containing list

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have hard time trying to explain behavior in following example:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Class1Proto
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int data1 = 1;
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string data2 = "MYRANDOMSTRING";
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ProtoChunk
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<Class1Proto> arr = new List<Class1Proto>();

    public const int PageSize = 4096;
}
```

Usage:

```
    byte[] page = new byte[ProtoChunk.PageSize];

    ProtoChunk originalData = new ProtoChunk();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Class1Proto p = new Class1Proto();
        p.data1 = i * 2;
        p.data2 = (i * 2).ToString();
        originalData.arr.Add(p);
    }

    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(page, writable:true))
    {
        Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(memStream, originalData, PrefixStyle.Fixed32);
    }

    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(page, writable:false))
    {
        ProtoChunk deserializedData = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<ProtoChunk>(memStream, PrefixStyle.Fixed32);
    }
```

My expectation would be that `originalData` and `deserializedData` should be identical. And they mostly are except that `deserializedData.arr[0].data1 == 1 while originalData.arr[0].data1 == 0`. All the other objects are identical, even including `originalData.arr[0].data2 and deserializedData.arr[0].data2` (string field).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

protobuf-net assumes "implicit zero defaults" - i.e. unless specific otherwise, members have a default value of zero, meaning: zero is not transmitted. This isn't purely arbitrary - this is actually the "proto3" specification (well... more or less; in "proto3", zero is the *only* permitted default).

Your code - particularly the property initializer - acts as though it has a default value of 1, so: when the zero isn't transmitted, the 1 still gets applied by your constructor, and that becomes the value (deserialization in protobuf is a "merge" operation - pre-existing values are retained, again accordance with the specification).

Options:

- tell protobuf-net about your default - add `[DefaultValue(1)]` to the property
- tell protobuf-net not to run the constructor (and property initializer) - add `SkipConstructor = true` to the `[ProtoContract]`
- tell protobuf-net not to assume this behaviour: `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.ImplicitZeroDefault = false;`
- add your own conditional serialization callbacks (I can give an example if you really want)

I'd use the first option, personally.